# ¿Alguien sabe pasar matrices como parámetro de una clase o función a otra?

Tags: java

¿Alguien sabe pasar matrices como parámetro de una clase o función a otra en Java?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu código?

Comment: En realidad, apenas surgio la necesidad, estoy realizando un metodo matematico llamado CRAMER. Tienes Idea?

Comment: [Esto (SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698283/passing-a-string-array-as-a-parameter-to-a-function-java) te puede ayudar.

Comment: ¿Porqué en SO en español estas preguntas no se cierran o ponen en espera desde un principio como en la versión en inglés?

Comment: @WeaponX esa pregunta la puedes publicar en [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Se pasa como cualquier variable. Por ejemplo, pasas un arreglo de enteros en un método así:

```
public void algo(int[] arreglo) {
}
```

Una matriz solo es un arreglo de dos o más  dimensiones. De manera que solo debes indicar las dimensiones que tiene tu matriz. Un argumento de una matriz de dos dimensiones de entero se define

```
public void algo(int[][] arreglo) {
}
```